# Error while adding Facebook Comment Box to my blog

Tags: facebook, comments, blogger

While trying to add Facebook comment Box to my Blog following error came up.

```
The widget with id "Blog1" cannot contain element: "div". A widget can only contain b:includable elements
```

I was trying with following code.

```
  <b:includable id='comment-form' var='post'>
  <div class="fb-comments" expr:data-href="data:post.url" 
  data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"/>
```

Comment: Could you share more information about where exactly were you trying to add this code in the `Blog1` widget ?